# Button Down & Up event

Tags: button, event-handling, windows-phone-8

I just started on Windows Phone 8 development.
And in normalt winforms i can do a OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp.

How would this translate to WP8 development? I need to trigger somthing if a button is pressed, and somthing else when it is released?

Answer (score 3):

Please try manipultionstarted and manipulationcompleted events for your requirement.

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button.ManipulationStarted += button_ManipulationStarted;
            button.ManipulationCompleted += button_ManipulationCompleted;         
        }

        void button_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textblock.Text += "\n mouse button up";
        }

        void button_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            textblock.Text += "\n mouse button down";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the events MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp